# How to test a camel route without loading beans

Tags: spring, mongodb, apache-camel

I have written a Camel Route which includes some components that reference a bean. Of course I want to unit test that route but I have problems writing the test independent of the bean.

To he exact, I am using the mongodb component to fetch all documents in a collection. This component requires a MongoClient bean that is automatically injected.

In my unit test, I replace the mongodb component with a mock component with stubbed data, using adviceWith() in the test setup. I also register the component with a Mockito.mock so, but the MongoClient always starts with a failed connection due to the fact that there is no db to connect to. Why I also believe that I might barking up the wrong tree and Spring is causing my issue.

The test is working kind of, but the test also starts to establish a connection to the mongodb. My personal goal is not to start a connection. Can anyone of you give me a hint what I should try.

The only way that I am familiar with is storing the endpoint urls in the properties file and referencing the keys in the application. I hope to find a better solution.

I am using a camel spring boot archetype with version 3.8 and enhanced the existing route and test.

Comment: Provide some code if you really want to get helped.

Comment: Look at advice with. If you have a copy of the CiA2 book then see the testing chapter that covers this.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `startCamelContext` method and replace the problematic endpoint there using `weaveById` or `weaveByToUri` with `AdviceWithRouteBuilder` before starting the context.

```java
@Override
protected void startCamelContext() throws Exception {
    
    context.getRouteDefinition("queryDBForTasks").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            weaveByToUri("jdbc:*")
                .replace()
                .to("mock:jdbc");
        }
    });
    
    super.startCamelContext();
}
```

After that at the start of a test you can use `AdviceWithRouteBuilder` with weave methods to control the behaviour of these mock endpoints.

```java
@Test
public void TestJDBCRoute() throws Exception {

    context.getRouteDefinition("queryDBForTasks").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            
            weaveByToUri("mock:jdbc")
                .after()
                .setBody(constant(getTasksForTest()));

            weaveAddLast()
                .setProperty("testResultCount").simple("${body.size()}")
                .to("mock:result");
        } 
    });

    MockEndpoint resultMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
    resultMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
    resultMockEndpoint.message(0)
        .exchangeProperty("testResultCount").isEqualTo(4);

    template.sendBody("direct:queryDBForTasks", null);

    resultMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

For any problematic routes with consumer endpoints like timers, cron jobs or ones that require beans or connections not available during testing you can use `removeRouteDefinition` in `startCamelContext` to remove said routes.

```java
@Override
protected void startCamelContext() throws Exception {
    
    context.removeRouteDefinition(
        context.getRouteDefinition("someRoute"));        
    super.startCamelContext();
}
```

Comment: You can configure the `CamelTestSupport` that advice with is in use, and when so, then it wont auto start the routes. Then you can do the advice and start Camel aftwards and then you wont have that JDBC no data source problem you talk about

Comment: Thanks, seems I had completely missed the `startCamelContext` of `CamelTestSupport`. Modified the answer accordingly.